# Android: UPnP device scanner sample

Tags: android, upnp

I'm wondering if anyone has an example of a UPnP device scanner which I can import to eclipse. I would like this since I can understand how it works a lot easier when I see what it does in the emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "device scanner" you mean "media controller" aka DMC. If you insist in having the DMC in Android emulator, then you can probably use [Cling UPnPBrowser](http://4thline.org/projects/download/misc/), which is basically a working example of how to use Cling in Android.

Observing and debugging in emulator is unnecessarily tedious too - if you want to learn UPnP, not as much Android. From the point of UPnP, the platform doesn't make any difference. [A corresponding desktop app](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/workbench/) is completely equal (regarding UPnP internals) and way more comfortable to play with.

Also, instead of diving into the code, i would suggest starting with [some basic documentation](http://upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-AVArchitecture-v1-20020625.pdf), so that you know what's the stuff that DMC is sending to the network and the other buzz on the wire even if DMC doesn't ask for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got Cling UPnP Browser running.

Comment: This example use cling 1 or 2? Thank you